# Outputting compounded data with google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to find how to do this online to no avail.

Let us say we have a spreadsheet of daily percentage changes as shown below , which is denoted by D3-D11:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfekO.png)

How would you output the compounded capital grows and falls on a daily basis assuming some starting capital?

So day one would be $1.009.

Day two would be (1.00946)(1.009)~$1.01854514.

Day three would be (1.00829)(1.00946)(1.009)~$1.027.

And so on.

Then, how would you populate these values as a separate column? So E3 would be 1.009, E4 would be 1.01854514, E5 would be 1.027, and so on. What formula produces this?

Doing it by hand is too time consuming. Looking for a formula. Spent hours trying  to find one no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the results you desire:

```
=PRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA($D$3:$D3+1))
```

Paste it into cell E3 of your sheet, then drag from the lower right hand corner of the cell down the column to autofill the formula into the rest of column E.

### Explanation

This makes use of a combination of absolute and relative referencing to achieve the desired results. `$D$3:$D3` will automatically be changed to `$D$3:$D4` and then `$D$3:$D5` and so on as the formula is filled down the column. The dollar signs prevent `$D$3` from changing but allow the row number of `$D3` to change.

Then =ARRAYFORMULA is used to add 1 to each value in the array. Finally, =PRODUCT is used to multiply every entry together.

Functions Used:

- [=ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [=PRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093502?hl=en)